# How to return a SQLPLUS variable in Python using cxOracle

Tags: python, oracle, sqlplus

I have following SQLPlus syntax. Now I need to run it in Python using cxOracle. How do I do that?

```
variable my_cnt number;
begin
   :my_cnt := 10;
    commit;
end;
.
/
select :my_cnt from dual;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

```
import cx_Oracle
connstr = 'scott/tiger@127.0.0.1:1521/xe'
orcl = cx_Oracle.connect(connstr)

curs = orcl.cursor()
number_var = curs.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
curs.execute(r"""BEGIN :my_cnt := 10; END;""", {'my_cnt':number_var})

print number_var.getvalue()

curs.close()
orcl.close()
```